# Custom SharePoint List forms in SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, jslink, sharepoint-addin, sharepointframework

We are migrating old SharePoint 2010 On Premise code to SharePoint Online.
Part of the SharePoint 2010 on premise code has **custom list forms** developed with visual Studio.

Thought of using **JSLink** for custom forms while migrating the code to SharePoint Online but it seems that JSLink is only supported in classic experience and not in modern new experience.

Is there any way we can develop custom list forms on SharePoint Online with **modern new experience**? Is it possible with SharePoint Framework?

**Note:**
Tried by adding forms to list instances on SharePoint Hosted Add In but it targets the *AppWeb* lists and not the lists on *HostWeb*.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use react in modern web part to build any custom form. We can reuse components.

[image]
Another option is to use Power Apps similar to info path to design and add validation on list form.

https://abdulazizfarooqi.wordpress.com/

Another option is to use Content Editor webpart and add bootstrap html forms.
I hope it may help u.

Answer (score 0):

Coding in Classic View is the only solution to your query. Once you are done coding in classic, you can switch/migrate to Modern View Experience.

In this way, your form will be visible and lists will also be consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Nope!.. Modern sites are totally different development model So JSLink is not possible but you can use SharePoint framework extension to achieve the customization for the list.

Please follow the link below
[JSLink to SPFX extensions](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions)

Please mark if accepted as answer